# Add a fixed value to get cumulative sum

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe , I want to add a fixed number 5 to the first element of the dataframe, to get cumulative sum

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Values': [10, 5000, 6000, 7000, 8000, 9000, 8000]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

Expected result like below, the first row is calculate 10 + 5 =15, second row is cumulative sum 15+5 = 20, then 20+5

[image]

please advise,thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) directly:

```
step = 5
df['add'] = np.arange(1, len(df)+1)*step+df['Values'].iloc[0]
```

Or:

```
step = 5
df['add'] = np.arange(step, len(df)*step+1, step)+df['Values'].iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
   Values  add
0      10   15
1    5000   20
2    6000   25
3    7000   30
4    8000   35
5    9000   40
6    8000   45
```

For fun, a pure pandas approach (but I wouldn't use it):

```
df['add'] = df.loc[[0], 'Values'].reindex(df.index).add(5, fill_value=0).cumsum()
```

Comment: np.arange(1, len(df)+1) is super neat, save work to create a new column to label 12,3,4,5... then multiply

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

```
import numpy as np
df['add'] = np.linspace(15, 45, 7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
a = np.full(len(df), 5)
a[0] = df.iloc[0,0]
df['add'] = a.cumsum()
```

---

Alternatively,

```
from itertools import accumulate
df['add'] = list(
    accumulate(range(len(df)-1), lambda acc, x: acc + 5, initial=df.iloc[0,0]))
```

---

Output:

```
   Values  add
0      10   10
1    5000   15
2    6000   20
3    7000   25
4    8000   30
5    9000   35
6    8000   40
```